# Places API missing tag Android

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using the Google places api and I am trying to parse the XML data to get a number of things including the rating. The only problem is that sometimes there isn't a rating tag (  shown below). How do I work around this problem?

```
<name>Zari</name>
<type>restaurant</type>
<type>food</type>
<type>establishment</type>
<formatted_address>212-214 Ifield Drive,            Crawley, United Kingdom</formatted_address>
<geometry>
<location>
 <lat>51.1218980</lat>
   <lng>-0.2135630</lng>
 </location>
 </geometry>
<rating>3.3</rating>
 </result>

 <result>
<name>Happy Meeting</name>
<type>restaurant</type>
<type>food</type>
<type>establishment</type>
<formatted_address>
<geometry>
<location>
<lat>51.1161600</lat>
<lng>-0.1844890</lng>
</location>
</geometry>
</result>
<result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if you got the ration or not. E.g. if you are parsing the data like this

```
    String temp=null;
    int rating;
        if (localName.equals("rating")){ //this code won't work if rating tag is
                                        // not present thus temp will be null

                    temp = attributes.getValue("rating");
                    rating = Integer.parseInt(temp);
    }
```

Now check further in your code that

```
if(temp==null){
rating=0; //or any that you want
}
```